# Additional i2c_gpio is not detected on Ubuntu Server 20.04 / RPi Zero 2 W / A+

Tags: pi-3, i2c, ubuntu, pi-zero-w-2

I'm trying to enable the second (GPIO-based i2c) on RPi Zero 2 W, Ubuntu server 20.04 to connect the following [sensor](https://www.waveshare.com/product/10-DOF-IMU-Sensor-C.htm). Note that the primary i2c pins are physically occupied as RPi is used as a hat for another [board](https://docs.petoi.com/nyboard/nyboard-v1_0). I've read tons of articles / similar questions, but have no luck detecting the sensor.

Here's my **/boot/config.txt**:

```
start_x=1
enable_uart=1
dtparam=i2c_arm=on 
dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus4,i2c_gpio_delay_us=8,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24
```

Here's the actual wiring: [image: wiring]

I've also added 2x4.7 resistors for SDA and SCL according to recommendations. Well, I tried w/o resistors as well.

When I run **i2cdetect -l**, I see only a default bus:

```
ubuntu@rpi:~$ i2cdetect -l
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
```

Which obviously gives nothing for **i2cdetect -y 1**:

```
ubuntu@rpi:~$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I see a sensor only if I connect it to the primary i2c port:

```
ubuntu@rpi:~$ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 77
```

Here's additional system info:

```
ubuntu@rpi:~$ uname -a
Linux rpi 5.4.0-1050-raspi #56-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 13 13:09:35 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Note that I've already tried to upgrade the kernel, but it seems like Ubuntu 20.04 has stuck on the 5.4 version.

Here's **dmesg** [log](https://pastebin.com/ZgV9DyuX).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I²C-gpio` is a software i2c controller; bus4 is meaningless. From the unclear photo it does not appear GPIO23/24 are connected.

Comment: With the great lumps of solder on the pins I am surprised it works at all.

Comment: @Milliways here's RPi pinout https://www.etechnophiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/BOARD-Layout-CMPLETE_800x506.jpg?ezimgfmt=rs:0x0/rscb40/ng:webp/ngcb40. Here's a real picture: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6638780/151785076-751dac50-5aec-41ae-a21f-21efb5d2cdc2.png. Lumps of solder are not interfering with each other. Bus removal doesn't affect anything. Anything else you can advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a number of experiments, I came up with the fact that Ubuntu on RPi ignores `/boot/config.txt` settings for some reason (or just overwrites them) in favor of `/boot/firmware` location. I examined `/boot/firmware/syscfg.txt` and found the same settings there. So then I've just blindly added `dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,...` to **syscfg** and after reboot, my i2c sensor magically appeared in the list. That's weird and disappointing as all the guides mention `/boot/config.txt` as a single point of truth. I wasted so many hours on that.

Answer (score 0):

`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio` works on *Raspberry Pi OS-Buster*
and reports
`i2c-22 i2c         ffffffff00000002.i2c                I2C adapter`

`dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=4` works

Who knows what Ubuntu does (or supports) as it uses its own kernel?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, it looks like i2c config changes should happen in /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt, and not /boot/firmware/syscfg.txt. syscfg.txt is meant to be edited by the pibootctl utility.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).